# How to use spring security to authenticate two different types of users?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring boot application, I will have two different types of users i.e.

1. Admin users
2. customers

These users will be stored in two different tables. 
These two tables will have only email id in common. Everything else will be different.

Also, the no. of customers will be huge like 1 to 5 Millions customers. While on the other hand, admin users will be very few like less than 10. Hence the two different tables.

I want to have two different login pages. One at /customer/login for all the customer and another at /admin/login for all the admins. Login details should be authenticated using their respective tables. On login customers should go to /customer/home and admins should go to /admin/home.

On logout customer should be redirected to /customer/login and admin to /admin/login

I am using java config for Spring security. How can this be done in spring security?

Below is my configuration for single user which works properly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Bean
    public Integer applicationSessionTimeout(){
        return applicationProperties.getSecurity().getSessionTimeout();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager(AccessDecisionVoterImpl accessDecisionVoter) {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> accessDecisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<?>>();
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new WebExpressionVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(accessDecisionVoter);
        UnanimousBased accessDecisionManager = new UnanimousBased(accessDecisionVoters);
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
        passwordEncoder.setStringDigester(stringDigester());
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public PooledStringDigester stringDigester() {
        PooledStringDigester psd = new PooledStringDigester();

        psd.setPoolSize(2);
        psd.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
        psd.setIterations(1000);
        psd.setSaltSizeBytes(16);
        psd.setSaltGenerator(randomSaltGenerator());

        return psd;
    }

    @Bean
    public RandomSaltGenerator randomSaltGenerator() {
        RandomSaltGenerator randomSaltGenerator = new RandomSaltGenerator();
        return randomSaltGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/static/**")
                .antMatchers("/i18n/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling().
                accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/checkLogin**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/checkLogin")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home?menu=homeMenuOption")
                .failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);
    }

}
```

Below is my UserDetailsService which checks in db for proper authentication.

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ModuleService moduleService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        log.debug("Authenticating : {}", userName);

        SecurityUser securityUser = null;

        try {

            User user = userService.findUserByEmail(userName);

            if (user != null) {
                log.debug("User with the username {} FOUND ", userName);
                securityUser = new SecurityUser(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user.getRole().getId()));
                securityUser.setUser(user);
            } else {
                log.debug("User with the username {}  NOT FOUND", userName);
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return securityUser;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Long roleId) {
        log.debug("Populating user authorities");

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        List<Module> allModules = moduleService.findAllModules();
        Map<Long, Module> moduleMap = new HashMap<Long, Module>();

        for(Module module : allModules){
            moduleMap.put(module.getModuleId(), module);
        }

        List<ModuleOperation> moduleOperationList = moduleService.findModuleOperationsByRoleId(roleId);

        for (ModuleOperation moduleOperation : moduleOperationList) {
            moduleOperation.setModuleName(moduleMap.get(moduleOperation.getModuleId()).getModuleName());
            authorities.add(moduleOperation);
        }

        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Comment: @J.West I generally use roles only. But, since, these are entirely different sets of users, we don't want to keep them together. Admins at max will have 5 columns and customers min will have 20-30 columns. So, you see the difference there.

Comment: I do not know what database you will use, but AFAIK with major providers (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MariaDB) there is no harm having many NULL columns in a record.

Comment: @ashishjmeshram The answer below is what I would suggest doing. Like he is saying, it doesn't make a difference if you persist an admin user into the same table and leave all the extra columns as `null`. Another issue with multiple login pages is that there will be no way to prevent someone from visiting either URI, and while a user couldn't login if they weren't an admin, it would still be confusing if someone landed on that page expecting to be able to login.

Answer (score 4):

It is really a bad idea to have different login pages for Spring security, because it is not the way it is designed for. You are going to fall into trouble to define the authentication entry point to use and will need a lot of boiling plate. According to your other requirements, I would propose you the following way:

- use one single login page with one single `AuthenticationManager` (the default `ProviderManager` will be fine)
- configure it with two different `AuthenticationProvider`s, both being `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, each pointing on one of you 2 user tables
- configure those provider to automatically set different roles, ROLE_ADMIN for the former that will process admins, ROLE_USER for the latter

That way you fully rely on SpringSecurity infrastructure with as little modifications as possible to meet your requirements.

But you should also wonder whether you really need different databases. At least for the major providers (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, ...) there is no harm in having many null columns in a record. IMHO you should do a serious analysis to compare both ways, either one single table (much simpler to setup for Spring Security) or two tables.

Comment: There is a slight change now in the requirement. Customer will login using their customer id while admin users will login using the email id. What is the better way now?

Comment: @ashishjmeshram: IMHO it should not matter. The login form will take an idand a password, and the 2 `AuthenticationProvider`s will try to process them, each taking its one. You can have an auxiliary form for admins with useful comments, but only one shall be the authentication entry point, and both should accept admin or customer credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question due to a problem I am also facing. Here is how I solved it. A little unconventional but very efficient. So what I did was To create 2 constructors in the UserDetails class that extends the UserDetails.

One that takes the Admin user type:

```
public UserDataUserDetails(Admin admin) {
    this.username = admin.getUsername();
    this.pwd = admin.getPassword();
    this.authorities = Arrays.stream(admin.getRole().toString().split(","))
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Second that takes the Customer user type:

```
public UserDataUserDetails(User user) {
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.pwd = user.getPassword();
    this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRole().toString().split(","))
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then I created 2 identical components that serves individual scenarios as stated in the snippet below. Explanation of the snippets: They are from 2 separate classes that extends UserDetailsService each.

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsernameEquals(username);
    return user.map(UserDataUserDetails::new)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new GeneralErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, false, "Invalid User", new String[]{"User with provided user name, \'" + username + "\' not found in our database!"}));
}

@Autowired
private AdminRepository adminRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<Admin> admin = adminRepository.findAdminWithUsername(username);
    return admin.map(UserDataUserDetails::new)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new GeneralErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, false, "Invalid User", new String[]{"User with provided user name, \'" + username + "\' not found in our database!"}));
}
```

So finally! What you want to do in your JwtAuthenticationFilter is:

```
@Autowired
private UserModelDetailsService userDetailsService;
@Autowired
private AdminModelDetailsService adminModelDetailsService;

UserDetails user = null;
        if (type.equals(Role.SUPER.toString()) || type.equals(Role.ADMIN.toString())){
            user = this.adminModelDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        } else {
            user = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I tried this since I have multiple User types, but I'm getting a Stackoverflow error when trying to log in. Could you perhaps share your SecurityConfig class please?

Comment: I would need to see your code to know what happened in yours @ServletException

Comment: I am currently only able to login with either a user or a admin, not both. How did you do your config

    private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    private final MyEmployeeDetailsService myEmployeeDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myEmployeeDetailsService); 
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

Comment: Not getting a stackoverflow error anymore, and I can't provide the full code bc of the character limit. If I replace the .setUserDetailsService() with an implementation of my own for the User, then only the User can log in, but not an Admin

Comment: Can you invite me to the code or do a teams call so i can help you sort it out? @ServletException